# I cant figure out how this void method works

Tags: java, arrays, void

My code is:

```
public class MyProgram {
    public void start() {
        int a = 1; 
        int[] b = { 1, 2, 3}; 
        int[] c = { 1, 2, 3}; 

        method1(a,  b[0], c); 

        System.out.println("a   = " + a); 
        System.out.println("b[0]   = " + b[0]); 
        System.out.println("c[0]   = " + c[0]); 
    }

    private  void method1(int x, int y, int[] z) {
        x++; 
        y = 10; 

        if ( z.length >= 1   ) {  
            z[0] = 100;  
        }
        System.out.println(x); 
        System.out.println(y); 
    }
}
```

The output is

```
a   = 1
b[0]   = 1
c[0]   = 100
```

I really have no idea why only c[0] has changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`private  void method1(int x, int y, int[] z)`

Note that `int` type is a primitive, so it's passed by value (value is copied over)

And `int[]` type is an array, so it's passed by reference (reference to the array is passed over)

So when you modify the `int` variables, you are changing the copies - they don't affect the variables outside of the scope of that function

When you modify the array, it's done through the reference passed in - so the changes persist.

Comment: You should be more clear, the array is still passed by value, its value is just a reference to some place in memory.

Answer (score 2):

```
 if ( z.length >= 1   ) {  
        z[0] = 100;  
    }
```

Because you changed it here and arrays are pass by "reference value" (another copy of this reference, still points to same object/array).

So, what happens here is when you following code executes:

```
method1(a,  b[0], c);
```

It passes 'c' reference value to method1.

Inside `method1`, you are not assigning any `new` array to this copy of reference value, so operations on this reference reflect on original array.

so `z[0]` updates reflects at `c[0]` index.

Answer (score 1):

Because array is passed by reference, and other variables are local.

Comment: to be more precise, there is only Pass-by-value in Java.  It is not "array is passed by reference".  It is "reference/pointer to array is passed, and it is passed by value"

Answer (score 1):

When you pass variables to methods in Java you pass their 'value' (because Java only supports pass-by-value). For 'reference-type' variables like arrays and objects you *still* pass their value, but their value is a reference to someplace in memory where the data is actually stored.

So any modifications you make to your array inside of your `method1` method will change the actual contents of the array.

Memory example:

```
                    (someplace in memory)
 -------            --------------
|   c   |  ----->   |     1      |   0
 -------            |     2      |   1
                    |     3      |   2
                    --------------
```

When you pass `c` to a method, the parameter in the method gets the 'value' of `c` which is actually a reference or a pointer to some space in memory where the array data is stored. Any changes you make to `c` in your method will be reflected in the array since it points to the same place in memory.

```
                    (someplace in memory)
 -------            --------------
|   c   |  ----->   |    100     |   0
 -------            |     2      |   1
                    |     3      |   2
                    --------------
```

Answer (score 1):

```
method1(a,  b[0], c);
```

Since, in Java, everything in passed by value, so the first two parameters `a`, and `b[0]`, when changed in the called method, will have no effect on the calling method. Because, when you change it, the value will be changed, and the original value remains unchanged.

However, and third parameter `c` is the reference of your array. Which is also passed by value. So, when you pass it to a method, a copy of reference is made, and the parameter in the called method (`z`), also points to the same array object.

Now, any change you make to your array, using the passed reference, will be reflected in all the reference pointing to that array.

```
private  void method1(int x, int y, int[] z)
```

So, in this method, `x` and `y` are different variables containing the same value as in `a` and `b`. Whereas, `z` has a different `reference` address that points to the same `array` object as pointed to by the original reference `c`.

```
         c[0] c[1] c[2]
         z[0] z[1] z[2] // So, if you change `z[0]`, `a[0]` will also see the change

c ---->  [ 1,   2,   3 ] -> // Any change in the array is reflected in 
          ^                 // both the reference a and z
          |
          |
z --------+

a -> someValue
x -> someValue -> // If we change this, the `someValue` for `a` won't be changed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would it NOT change?

c is pointing to an array object. When you are passing c to method1, a copy of c (the pointer/reference, not the array itself) will be passed as z.  However, z is still pointing to the same array instance that c is pointing to.  If you change the content of that array instance thru z, of course it will be reflected when you access thru c afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

The method method1 has 3 parameters, the first two being primitive int type and the last one being array type. Java doesn't pass method arguments by reference; it passes them by value.

primitive type are not object hence copies of the primitive type will be passed into the method1

You need to understand that Java copies and passes the reference by value, not the object. When you create an object in java, you access that object via its reference. When you call method1, what java will do is obtain the reference to the array, make a copy of that reference and pass it to the method1. It implies that you will have two references pointing to the array (one in the start method and one in the method1 method). Hence any modification being made in the method1 will eventually affect the array since the reference being used in the method1 points to the array